# What are some of the configuration parameters that I can tweak in MySQL to improve its performance without doing any code changes?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm managing a MySQL server for testing purposes, and I was wondering if I can utilize the 4GB RAM available on the machine to improve MySQL's performance without doing any code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MySQLTuner](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl)(High-performance MySQL optimization script).

```
# wget http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl
--2011-01-31 06:49:46--  http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl
Resolving mysqltuner.pl... 174.143.142.58
Connecting to mysqltuner.pl|174.143.142.58|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 39054 (38K) [text/plain]
Saving to: `mysqltuner.pl'

100%[==============================================================================================================================>] 39,054      54.6K/s   in 0.7s    

2011-01-31 06:49:49 (54.6 KB/s) - `mysqltuner.pl' saved [39054/39054]

# perl mysqltuner.pl

 >>  MySQLTuner 1.0.1 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
Please enter your MySQL administrative login: root
Please enter your MySQL administrative password:
```

Answer (score 0):

`wget mysqltuner.pl` and run it with `perl mysqltuner.pl`. It was written by Major Hayden to suggest database optimizations.